# facebook search all people who share an interest within a city

Tags: python, facebook

how to find all people in a city who share an interest using facebook api. Is facebook graph search available as api or some python module.

facebook graph search is available at: `https://www.facebook.com/about/graphsearch`

Comment: You're much more likely to get an answer if you provide some code. We are not here to code things from scratch for you.

Comment: i am not asking for code, just point me to an api, module or resource where such type of query is possible

Comment: This is currently not possible via an API IMHO

Comment: @Tobi so the only way is scraping the results?

Comment: You mean parsing the result of the GraphSearch website? I think this wouldn't make sense. You could use the standard Search API to find publically available info on persons, but the likes/interests always require a permission-based Access Token. So I doubt that it's possible to achieve what you desire to do...

Comment: @Tobi i am saying web scraping the search results using mechanize module

Comment: Well, then good luck with that. Please check their platform policy and see whether it confines with it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for.  You can take a look and contact this developer team may be they can help you. They have built a tool for finding facebook's hidden interests using Facebook Graph API. This tool offers thousands of results from Facebook. https://findfacebookinterest.com/ Here is a change to discover hidden interests to target your social media audience